# In ES6, how do I get my class in a js file to be seen as defined in the html file?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6

This morning I started refactoring my javascript in an app I'm doing to ES6 with the understanding that all the modern browser versions support it fully.  The 'main' module though inside the jQuery document ready function - In Chrome debugger, I get an error that my class is not defined!  Here is my class in a nutshell (not all of it, just a skeleton and maybe a function or 2):

```
let UsherSchedule = (function()
{
    var  mssArrDays =
        [   "Sunday"
        ,   "Monday"
        ,   "Tuesday"
        ,   "Wednesday"
        ,   "Thursday"
        ,   "Friday"
        ,   "Saturday"
        ];

    var mssArrMonths =
        [   "January"
        ,   "February"
        ,   "March"
        ,   "April"
        ,   "May"
        ,   "June"
        ,   "July"
        ,   "August"
        ,   "September"
        ,   "October"
        ,   "November"
        ,   "December"
        ];

    var mObjChanges;
    var mLstObjConsistory;
    var msCurrentEditingId;
    var miCurrentMonth;
    var miCurrentYear;
    var mObjSchedule;

    //...
    class UsherSchedule
    {
         constructor()
         { }

        //...
    }

     return({   UsherSchedule   });
})();
```

I don't know - Do I need an export statement at the end after the closure is done?  Eclipse claims it's an illegal entity!  And in my index file, I have the script tag and my inline script tag here:

```
<script src="resources/js/UsherSchedule.js" type="module"> </script>
<script>
    $(document)
        .ready(function()
        {
            new UsherSchedule().init();
        });
</script>
```

I've tried putting "use strict"; and "import { UsherSchedule } from "/resources/js/UsherSchedule.js" and while Chrome debugger works for the use strict, it errors on the { of the 2nd :-O

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  I've always worked with ES5 and closures and never ran into issues like this until ES6 today.

Comment: I don't have the definition inside the ready() handler.  I just instantiate the instance of the class in there.  The definition is in its own module UsherSchedule.js inside a closure to allow me to have private variables

Comment: If you're using `<script type="module">`, then you have to explicitly export and then import anything you want to share and use and it won't automatically be shared into the global scope.  This is not your grandma's `<script>` tag any more - `import` and `export` are required.  Some examples here: https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/

Comment: Also, you can get rid of the IIFE in a module.  It's already wrapped into its own private scope.  Only exported things can be touched by other code.

Comment: My point is - if I have a method - say "buildBlahBlah" that I want to be private/protected within the class - My understanding & so far experience is that I can have an instance of UsherSchedule (objUsherSchedule to just say) and call objSchedule.buildBlahBlah() - I don't want that - I want the method to be private - In UsheSchedule the ONLY methods I want public are init() & the rest to be private/protected - Those methods are all in the IIFE & init() calls upon them or a subset of them (which those call the rest).  Plus, "this.(variable)" is public within the class to my knowledge :-/

Comment: Javascript does not have private methods.  They don't really exist.  You can make private functions that operate on your object, but they aren't actually methods because any actual method is available to the outside world either via the prototype or via a property on the object.

Comment: FYI, if your question is really all about how to implement a private method on an object, then you really need to rewrite your question because that's not at all what your question asks right now.  In fact, I don't think your question even contains the word "private" at all.

Comment: I just put "export default UsherSchedule;" at the end of UsherSchedule.js and I put "import {UsherSchedule} from './UsherSchedule';" at the top of the inline script before the ready handler and I got Chrome debugger saying "SyntaxError: Unexpected token {" - So it's got a problem w/ my import statement for some reason - that's what a website had for syntax for import to state what you want to import - is it not the correct syntax?

Comment: It's not about private functions - The IIFE is 'for' the private functions - I'm very experienced in using closures in javascript to produce the illusion of privacy because it's totally impossible given an IIFE that returns an object exporting methods/functions to see, much less use the o the other methods that aren't returned in the object.  I'm just not sure how to get Chrome to see my class once it's been included into the index.jsp - my import statements don't seem to work.

Comment: Well, with the right versions of Javascript, you need to use import and export if you're using `<script type="module">`.  I gave you a link above that shows exactly how to do it.  If you are trying an example from that and it isn't working, then show us exactly the code you are trying in your question and what errors you are getting.  Putting code into comments doesn't really show us enough to understand what you're trying.  Put a whole reproducible block into your question itself.

Comment: More examples here on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import.  Lots of other examples you can find with Google.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning an `Object` whose attribute `UsherSchedule` has as value the `UsherSchedule` class.

Basically, if we call `_UsherSchedule` the class inside the closure, you have something like this:

```
UsherSchedule = { 
    UsherSchedule: _UsherSchedule
}
```

This is because of the [deconstructing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

**How does it work?**

*ES6+*

```
let extFoo = (function() {
    const foo = 'bar'

    return { foo }
})();
```

*ES5*

```
var extFoo = (function() {
    var foo = 'bar'

    return { foo: foo }
})();
```

In both the cases `extFoo` is

```
{ foo: 'bar' }
```

---

**EDIT**

If having private stuff is a priority, you may want to take a look at [this](http://2ality.com/2016/01/private-data-classes.html), which illustrates some "modern" (in 2016...) techniques to accomplish what you ask.

If you're not too into changing your implementation, replacing

```
return({   UsherSchedule   });
```

with

```
return UsherSchedule;
```

should do the trick.

---

**FURTHER EDIT**

Yes, jfriend00, was right :D So, along with what I said before you could either do:

1) remove the `type="module"` from the script tag;

2) keep it and add:

```
// resources/js/UsherSchedule.js
...
export default UsherSchedule
```

and on HTML

```
<script type="module">
    import UsherSchedule from './resources/js/UsherSchedule.js';
    ...
</script>
```

Please pay attention to the leading `./` in the module path, as absolute import are still not supported.

Comment: So if the closure is returning the class, why can't the object UsherSchedule which by equation is == to the class, construct the instances of the class?  I want to have priv. variables.  Every method, getter, and setter in an ES6 class is public which I don't like - IT's not OOP friendly.  Esp. since in UsherSchedule, while there were MANY methods, only 1 did I want to be visible from the outside - aka exported - & that's init().  The others would be only called from within the class.  So how'd I have priv. variables & a class in ES6 if I can't have a class w/in a closure & return the class?

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work :-(  I still get that UsherSchedule is not defined.

Comment: I think you're missing (as I did also) that the OP is using `<script type="module">` so all shared data has to be exported, then imported to use it.

Comment: So do I need to (in UsherSchedule.js) put at the end "export default UsherSchedule;" or put (instead of let at the beginning) "export" or how do I phrase it?  Also in index.jsp, do I put (I presume before the $(document.ready()) handler) "import { UsherSchedule } from "./UsherSchedule.js";"?  or how would that be put?  Whenever I put the import thing - Chrome would yell at the curly braces as bad token and Eclipse yells at both export and import as bad tokens for some reason - I use Eclipse Neon for the time being but after reading, I understand that the problem is in Oxygen too :-(

Comment: So I don't need a ; after export? Also not just Chrome but also Edge and Eclipse were complaining about the words export and import - Last night I reverted it to ES5 but I'll re-refactir it today & hope it works *prays*

Comment: Ok I just made the changes again before I have to leave in about 20 mins for my appointment but I'm getting a different error now - Both eclipse and chrome are complaining about the export keyword in all my modules and in index.jsp, it says: Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './resources/js/UsherSchedule.js' does not provide an export named 'UsherSchedule' - I tried w/ and w/o semicolon at the end of the export statement, w/ and w/o curly braces around UsherSchedule in both the export and import statements, w/ and w/o the .js extension in the import statement too..